# Like a page via foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

Can't find an endpoint providing "Like a page" (not a  page update) via the API. Any suggestions? Looking here https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/pages/pages

Answer (score 0):

You won't find such an endpoint: "like a page" is explicitly intended to be done by users, never via an API. None of the major platforms that allow things like Likes provide API endpoints for that action (Facebook doesn't, Foursquare doesn't either) because they do not want developers gaming the system and inadvertently (or on purpose) performing those actions without user consent.

So no: you're probably never going to find an API endpoint for that.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for this endpoint is coming soon (we're in the process of auditing our API to document the new APIs introduced by #allnew4sq)

The endpoint is /pages/USER_ID/like and without any additional params probably does what you want it to do.